# Extending Resolv::DNS to also get SPF resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns, spf, resolv

I am trying to extend `Resolv::DNS` to be able to get SPF resources. For this, I've simply added the following:

```
class Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::SPF < Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT
end

class Resolv::DNS::Resource::SPF < Resolv::DNS::Resource::TXT
end
```

When I now use `SPF`instead of `TXT` for querying, I get an empty hash. So I tried digging further.. on [resolv.rb line 516](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_353/lib/resolv.rb#L516), the type class is provided as second argument when creating a `Message` object, which is located on [line 1257](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_353/lib/resolv.rb#L1257). However, there stops my understanding of how things work.

Can anyone enlighten me or give me some guidance?

Comment: can you give me an example of a domain that you are trying to get the SPF record for?  Since SPF records are just TXT records, this might not work the way you are trying to do it.

Comment: AFAIK, writing spf records as TXT is just for compatibility reasons, there is an actual SPF. Usually, you write both, but I want to catch the case where one just entered SPF and not TXT records. I've set up one on `notionlab.ch` to test this. `dig -t spf` returns only the spf one, and `dig -t txt` only the txt one.

Answer (score 0):

I found out by querying my domain that `Resolv` seems to auto generate classes for record types it does not recognize. What you can do is query for all records and then filter on the type code. [SPF records have type code 99](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408#section-3.1.1), so you end up with something like this:

```
require 'resolv'

resolver = Resolv::DNS.new
all_records = resolver.getresources('example.com', Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::ANY)
spf_records = all_records.select { |r| r.class::TypeValue == 99 }
spf_records.each do |record|
  puts(record.data)
end
```

It's a bit ugly how you query the type code (`Resolv` creates a `TypeValue` constant on the generated classes, but adds no way to get this value from instances as far as I can see).